# mouse interaction using actionscript 2 in FLASH

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

How to create the mouse interaction using actionscript 2 in FLASH.
Below are my as3. i would like to downgrade as2. Any one can help me to come of this?
Also i would like to know can we do it in AS2 or not. i am very first in flash.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var w:int = 300;
var h:int = 250;
var mdist:int = _bg.width - w;
var mdisty:int = _bg.height - h;

var coef:Number = 0.1;
var autoX:Number =  -  mdist;
var autoSpeed:Number = ( mdist / (24 * 15) );// (distance in pixel / (fps * secs);
var autoMove:Boolean = true;
var autoDirection:int = 1;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stage_MouseOut);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, stage_MouseOver);
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this_EnterFrame);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this_Click);
this.buttonMode = true;

_bg.x =  -  mdist;
_bg.y =  -  mdisty >> 1;
_copy.mouseEnabled = false;
_copy.mouseChildren = false;
_logo.mouseEnabled = false;
_logo.mouseChildren = false;

function this_EnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    if (autoMove) {
        _bg.x = autoX;
        _bg.y += (-mdisty / 2 - _bg.y) * 0.2;
        autoX +=  autoSpeed * autoDirection;

        if (autoX > 0 && autoDirection == 1) {
            autoX = 0;
            autoDirection = -1;
        } else if (autoX < -mdist && autoDirection == -1) {
            autoX =  -  mdist;
            autoDirection = 1;
        }
    } else {
        moveScene(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

function moveScene(px:int, py:int):void {
    var xx:int = Math.min(w,Math.max(0,px));
    var yy:int = Math.min(h,Math.max(0,py));
    var dx:Number = xx / w;
    var dy:Number = yy / h;
    _bg.x += (-mdist * dx -_bg.x) * 0.2;
    _bg.y += (-mdisty * dy -_bg.y) *0.2;
}
```

Regards,
HH

Answer (score 1):

```
var coef:Number = 0.1;
var autoX:Number =  -  mdist;
var autoSpeed:Number = ( mdist / (24 * 15) );// (distance in pixel / (fps * secs);
var autoMove:Boolean = true;
var autoDirection:int = 1;

var mouseListener:Object = new Object();
mouseListener.onMouseOut = function():Void
{

}

mouseListener.onMouseOver = function():Void
{

}

mouseListener.onMouseUp = function():Void
{

}

stage.addListener(mouseListener);

_bg.x =  -mdist;
_bg.y =  -mdisty >> 1;
_copy._enabled = false;
_logo._enabled = false;

stage.onEnterFrame = function () 
{
    if (autoMove) {
        _bg.x = autoX;
        _bg.y += (-mdisty / 2 - _bg.y) * 0.2;
        autoX +=  autoSpeed * autoDirection;

        if (autoX > 0 && autoDirection == 1) {
            autoX = 0;
            autoDirection = -1;
        } else if (autoX < -mdist && autoDirection == -1) {
            autoX =  -  mdist;
            autoDirection = 1;
        }
    } else {
        moveScene(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

function moveScene(px:int, py:int):void {
    var xx:int = Math.min(w,Math.max(0,px));
    var yy:int = Math.min(h,Math.max(0,py));
    var dx:Number = xx / w;
    var dy:Number = yy / h;
    _bg.x += (-mdist * dx -_bg.x) * 0.2;
    _bg.y += (-mdisty * dy -_bg.y) *0.2;
}
```